# Install xrdp and use KDE on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, xrdp

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.4 system and have KDE installed on it.  I would like to get xrdp running on it with Kubuntu desktop. Googling around it seems that I should be able to just install xrdp and then change the xstartup file.

When I go to install xrdp it tells me it is going to remove kubuntu-desktop. Why is xrdp trying to remove KUbuntu?

```
Recommended packages:
  xorgxrdp
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kubuntu-desktop xorg xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xrdp
```

I would like to use KDE as the window manager, as that is what I have been using natively. Is that possible?

Comment: The best way to use KDE on Ubuntu is to install Kubuntu which is the official flavor of Ubuntu that uses the KDE desktop. Ubuntu offers several flavors with different desktops for this very reason: it's generally difficult and messy to change desktop environments on an installed system

Comment: FYI: I would check your system is updated, as an up-to-date *bionic* (18.04) system will report itself as 18.04.5, so if yours is reporting itself as 18.04.4, you're 6+ months behind on security patches & upgrades.. (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, actual installs upgrade to it before that date)   Also KDE Plasma is a desktop, using `kwin` as its window manager.